# Selecting similar following groups of faces

Tags: workflow, selection-tools

How can I do this kind of selection without repeating the same operation several times until the vase is selected all around?

[image]

At the moment I select the first face on top and than the last on bottom holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> and than I pass to the following strip, leaving one unselected.
Is there a faster way? Maybe a "repeat" like function or so?

Answer (score 9):

This route may seem a bit long-and-winding.. but it's the kind of habit I've got into, until someone comes along and points out what I've been missing all along...

- Select one of the edges you will **not** want, and the next in sequence.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> 'Select Next Active', until the  interval-selection is complete
- Header > Select > Loops > 'Edge Rings'
- <kbd>H</kbd> hide the selected edges
- <kbd>A</kbd> select all, (Switch to Face Mode, if you like)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> 'Reveal Hidden', with 'Select' **unchecked** in its  <kbd>F9</kbd> Adjust Last Operation panel.

[image]

Comment: It works, thank you.

Comment: Okay, this is old but just as a tip: after hiding the edges with H, everything remaining visible should be unselected. So instead of selecting all and unchecking "Select" after revealing the hidden faces, just leave everything at default. This way it's just two steps after selecting the edges H, Alt+H instead of four H, A, Alt+H, Uncheck "Select".

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Doooh! Of course. Sometimes I can be very 'clunk'... 'clunk' ... 'clunk' literal.

Answer (score 6):

Just select the top loop, and let Blender do the rest

1. Select the top loop using <kbd>Alt + Left Click</kbd>
2. Go *Select > Checker Deselect*
3. Go *Select > Similar > Coplanar*

[image]

Comment: This does not work in my case since the faces are non coplanar.

Comment: Hi :). There's a threshold value for faces that aren't perfectly coplanar. I don't have your exact mesh, just showing the tools available that might make you work easier ;)

Comment: This still wouldn't work because it would start selecting faces around the curve. @JachymMichal

Comment: If you change the threshold the result will not be ok because also the top ring will be all selected again